# SwiftUI toolbar not covering top of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a CommentView in my app that lists all comments for a post. The problem I am having is that the list of comments appears under the toolbar because the tool bar does not cover to top part of the iOS frame.

See attached image where I circled the issue in red, note that the tool bar appears directly under where I circled red so comments should not show above that..

Also this view is inside of a parent NavigationView hierarchy.

How can I make my tool-bar cover the top part of the iOS frame so that the comments cannot be seen at the top? Below is my code...

[image]

Thank you

```
 struct CommentView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    @StateObject var commentVM = CommentViewModel()
        
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(commentVM.comments, id: \.id) { comment in
                CommentViewRow(comment: comment)
            }.onDelete { indexSet in
                determineWhoseComment(indexSet)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        .navigationBarTitle("Comments", displayMode: .inline)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                ZStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                            self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        }
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.backward")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .font(.system(size: CHEV_NAV_SIZE, weight: .semibold))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("TextColor"))
                    })
                    Button(action: {}, label: {})
                }
            }
        }).padding(.top, 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue: the list in your example does not overlap the status bar. Except... when the `.ignoreSafeArea()` modifier is placed somewhere in the parent `NavigationView`. If you post the code for the parent view, maybe the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Why are you using two buttons in the same toolbar item? That's unnecessary, also why are you hiding the default navigation bar back button, is this view presented using a sheet? Very unclear what the end goal is.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution for iOS 15. The correct way of using `toolbar` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/toolbar(content:)-5w0tj). Also `navigationBarTitle(_:displayMode:)` is deprecated, so you can set the display mode in the parent view instead of the comment view. There's also the dismiss Environment you can use.

```swift
struct CommentView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var hovering: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1..<10) {_ in
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec id arcu quis diam ornare maximus. Ut non efficitur nisi. Nam eget eleifend nibh. Pellentesque molestie augue sit amet orci vulputate, commodo malesuada lectus gravida. Maecenas tristique vulputate lobortis. Praesent augue enim, fermentum vel ornare laoreet, consequat at justo. Nam dignissim urna a dictum ultrices.")
            }
        }
        .listRowBackground(hovering ? Color.gray : Color.primary)
        .hoverEffect()
        //.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
        //.navigationBarTitle("Comments", displayMode: .inline) is Deprecated
        .listStyle(.plain)
        .navigationTitle("Comments")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button(action: {
                    dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Label("Close", systemImage: "xmark")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: CommentView()) {
                    Text("Comments")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}
```

[image: toolbar]